# powerbi slicer update adapt to another slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a dimension table with column A, B, C, D, E. And I create the start model to link column A to Table A, column B to table B, column C to table C, column D to table D, column E to table E. The 5 columns doesn't follow the hierarchy structure. And I need to create the slicers for each column based on the dimension table.

The data example distribution is:

```
A1, B1, C1, D1, E1
A1, B2, C3, D3, E2
A2, B2, C2, D2, E3
A2, B3, C2, D3, E4
```

The slicer A may first have value A1, A2, and then if the user select A1, the slicer B may just provide choice B1 & B2 (B3 may be trimmed due to slicer A). How could I achieve this with each slicer change due to the up level slicers?

Actually I create a measure count for the table and add the the filter with condition > 0 for each slicer. This works at the beginning, but due to the single select setting for the slicer, after all the slicers have been selected, there is no choice to change for all the slicers.

What I want is that slicer A may contains choice A1, A2, and for slicer B if slicer select A1 then it will provide choice B1, B2. And if slicer B select B2 then slicer C have option C2, C3, etc. How could I achieve? Thanks.

Comment: When you say `there is no choice to change for all the slicers`, does this mean that you have filtered to the point where no more rows will return?  Trying to understand exactly what the issue is.  Also, setting the relationships to filter both directions can help with the type of slicer behavior that I think you're looking for.

Comment: As I have created the metrics cnt from the dimension table and add this filter cnt > 0 to all the slicers, after select each of the slicers then each slicer would have exact one value and thus there won't be any more choice for me to switch to other candidate for each field.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution based on conventional single-direction relationships that make the data model easier to work with. Generally, avoiding bi-directional filters is a good idea, since these can introduce a lot of complexity to other aspects of model design.

We start off with a simplified model to demonstrate the technique, it is not as complex as your own, but has the necessary components:

[image]

Here `Table A` and `Table B` are DAX tables, but these should ideally be an output from Power Query instead, to avoid such components in the data model. However, the tables are calculated using `DISTINCT`:

```
Table A = DISTINCT ( 'Table'[A] )
Table B = DISTINCT ( 'Table'[B] )
```

In our canvas view, we establish our test visuals: a table visual based on `Table` and slicers based on `Table A` and `Table B`:

[image]

To determine which values in `Table A` and `Table B` that are shown, we will add a measure that is evaluated for each of the available slicer options that will determine whether the option represents available data in `Table` based on the current filtering context.

We do this by simply counting rows in `Table` for each option. We add the following measure that returns 1 if there are any rows visible for the current slicer option:

```
Slicer Filter = 
IF ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ) > 0 , 1 )
```

We apply this measure as a **visual level filter** on all the relevant slicers, shown here for the `Table B` slicer. This will force the slicer to only show values in `Table B` for which there are visible rows in `Table`, without having to use bi-directional filters:

[image]

Now if we select `A1` or `A2` in `Table A` slicer, the `Table B` slicer updates accordingly:

[image]

Apply the same visual level filter on all relevant slicers, and you have your solution without introducing complex changes to your data model relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the nice detailed explanation. Actually I already applied the way you did here before, but there might still be some gap for me to get the solution. Later the day when I wrote the question I thought more on this and find one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have created your tables like this:

Main Table:

[image: MainTable]

And Other tables created by calculated tables using DAX:

```
Table A = VALUES(MainTable[A])
Table B = VALUES(MainTable[B])
Table C = VALUES(MainTable[C])
Table D = VALUES(MainTable[D])
Table E = DISTINCT(MainTable[E])
```

Now Let's model the tables:

[image: BiDirectional]

See picture

[image: DFER]

Now let's test it with slicers:

[image: Action_01]

[image: Action_02]

I hope This is what you want!

Comment: I would consider bi-directionality here an anti-pattern. Consider instead measure-based visual filters on slicers to determine which values are shown.

Comment: No! I prefer to make it on the model instead of doing it for every measure I defined.

Comment: You would only need one measure here to determine what is shown in all the slicers - you just count rows in the main table and show what is `>0`.

Comment: Nice; but doing it on the model looks more solid to me!

Comment: Thanks. I already have the distinct tables and models there. This may be a good choice for some conditions but not suitable for my cases. Maybe I didn't explain the question clear here.

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to thank Marcus and Ozan's answers, and they are helpful for PBI development. Here for this question, I did think more the day and had one solution.

I may need to created more derived dimension tables based on the full dimension table:

- Slicer A: a new dimension table **DA** with only distinct **column A** from the full dimension table, and set filter row count table DA > 0
- Slicer B: a new dimension table **DB** with only distinct **columns A, B** from the full dimension table, and set filter row count table DB > 0
- Slicer C: a new dimension table **DC** with only distinct **columns A, B, C** from the full dimension table, and set filter row count table DC > 0
- Slicer D: a new dimension table **DD** with only distinct **columns A, B, C, D** from the full dimension table, and set filter row count table DD > 0

In this way we could from slicers top down to select the value candidates from the data for each. Slicer A may have all the distinct column A values, and Slicer B may just have the column B values given column A value, and so on.